# Can static linking of libc be considered a countermeasure for ret2libc attack?

Tags: linux, security, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Let's consider modern GNU/Linux distro build around gcc and glibc. Let's compare static PIEs vs dynamic PIEs (meaning the ASLR is effective not only for the stack) and static non-PIEs vs dynamic non-PIEs. Not PIEs with non-PIEs.

My (related) questions are:

1. Can static linking of libc be considered a countermeasure for ret2libc attack?
2. Is it easier for an attacker to discover the address of a chosen libc function in dynamically linked program? If yes, in what way?
3. Is this possible that a function of choice of the attacker (e.g. system()) is not even present in a statically linked binary, whereas it is always there in a dynamically linked one?

Comment: My opinion: yes, no, yes.  But this will probably be closed as mostly opinion based.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ad.1 Can you write in what way? Ad.3 Is the whole dynamic library always mapped in the address space of a process or are shared objects somehow modular (similar to static libs consisting of several object files, which may be linked separately)?